# How to find the webkit's flow of rendering?

Tags: javascript, css, html, webkit

I am new to webkit. I have started analyzing the source code of webkit.

I need to know the immediate API that is called to render the UI as soon as the top layer javascript completes the execution of a function.

For example,

```
<html>
<body onload="loadPage();">
<div id = "div1">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadPage()
{
      document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "WebKit";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now as soon as the control comes out of the loadPage() function in javascript, webkit's API has to be called to render the text on the screen.

Help me how to trace the entire flow...

Thanks & Regards
Naveen.